# Reopen: New manager directly emailing team from personal email, yet they do not start for 3 months

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/102881) was closed as *seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies*. I see nothing in the body of that question that is specific to that company, or that refers to a policy specific to that company, or that is in any way legal in nature.

---

The question is from 2017 . If you're wondering why we should bother, it's because we close old questions as our standards evolve, so we might as well open old questions for the same reason. Doesn't mean we have to go on a crusade, but doesn't hurt to point them out when we find them.

Comment: I recall I VTC because the "right" approach is ambiguous and dependent on the company. I'm on mobile, so can't move freely; will check it again when I get to PC to reconsider.

Comment: Yup, I reread it and still find it broad and dependent on the company. I see that someone even casted a vote to delete. I won't cast vote to delete, but won't cast vote to reopen also.

Comment: @DarkCygnus The company will of course react according to its own policies - but the OP is not the company, and he has no policies of his own :) This is why I disagree with the close reason as stated. But yes, please consider adding that as an answer so we can comment properly

Answer (score 1):

Yup, I reread it and **still find it broad and dependent on the company**.

I see that someone even casted a vote to delete. I won't cast vote to delete, but won't cast vote to reopen also on it's current state.